# Java EE Netbeans Maven EJB Module (MySQL) Error

Tags: java, mysql, maven, netbeans, glassfish

I am using Netbeans 7.3.1 and glassfish 4.0. I've created a simple Maven EJB Project. What I'm trying to do is simply delete one row from my table (MySQL Database). 
I keep getting this error:

```
    Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton MyTester. Please see server.log for more details.
The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.performDeploy(ExecutionChecker.java:178)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.executionResult(ExecutionChecker.java:130)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:212)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

Session Bean:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp1;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

@Singleton
@LocalBean
@Startup
public class MyTester {

@PersistenceContext(name="com.mycompany_myApp1_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
EntityManager em;
    @PostConstruct
    public void myMain(){
        Staff staff = em.find(Staff.class, 5);
        System.out.println("deleting...");
        em.remove(staff);
    }
}
```

Staff.java:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp1;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
public class Staff implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer staffId;

    private String name;
    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;

    private String gender;
    @Column(name = "salary")
    private Integer salary;

    @Lob
    private byte[] pic;

    public byte[] getPic() {
        return pic;
    }

    public void setPic(byte[] pic) {
        this.pic = pic;
    }

    public Staff() {
    }

    public Staff(Integer staffId) {
        this.staffId = staffId;
    }

    public Integer getStaffId() {
        return staffId;
    }

    public void setStaffId(Integer staffId) {
        this.staffId = staffId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Integer getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(Integer salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (staffId != null ? staffId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Staff)) {
            return false;
        }
        Staff other = (Staff) object;
        if ((this.staffId == null && other.staffId != null) || (this.staffId != null && !this.staffId.equals(other.staffId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.mycompany.myapp1.Staff[ staffId=" + staffId + " ]";
    }

    void getGender(String m) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>myApp1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <name>myApp1</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
            <id>eclipselink</id>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <name>Repository for library EclipseLink (JPA 2.1)</name>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="com.mycompany_myApp1_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>asas</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The thing is if I want to just add a row to the table for example:

```
public void myMain(){
Staff staff = new Staff();
staff.setName("John");
staff.setAge(22);
em.persist(staff);
}
```

I get no errors, all just work fine and I see the result in my database! Please help.
Also if I change state from @Singleton to @Stateless or @Stateful there is no errors, but database does not change. What is going on?

Comment: seems to be your deployment not succss

Comment: Have you checked the server.log file for any other errors, like the exception suggests?

Comment: .log is very long.begining:`WARNING:   Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'STAFFID' in 'field list'
Error Code: 1054
Call: SELECT STAFFID, age, GENDER, NAME, PIC, salary FROM STAFF WHERE (STAFFID = ?)
 bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadObjectQuery(name="readStaff" referenceClass=Staff sql="SELECT STAFFID, age, GENDER, NAME, PIC, salary FROM STAFF WHERE (STAFFID = ?)")'`

Answer (score 0):

Today I tried to run my application again. After I clicked run, Netbeans starts downloading some stuff. And turns out everything works fine! I got one warning:

```
WARNING:   Class 'javax.ejb.PostActivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
```

but my application was successfully deployed and record has been removed from the table! This is really weird but turns out restarting netbeans fixed the issue.